# VB6: Read CSV File Into Access Table Using DoCmd.TransferText Error

Tags: csv, import, vb6

In a VB6 program, with an Access 2000 database, I want to read a .CSV file, with table field names in the first record, into a new Access table.

Here is my VB6 code:

With CreateObject("Access.Application")
      .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Database1.accdb"
      .DoCmd.TransferText , , newTable, importFile, True
      .Quit
   End With

The DoCmd.TransferText command gives me the following error:

Error # 3107 (MSAccess: Record(s) cannot be added; no insert permission on 'Table Name'.)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seeking clarification - are you running this `with` block from the database you are also opening through `.OpenCurrentDatabase`? If so, it is my understanding that call is for opening Access from another application ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837226(v=office.15).aspx)), so you may be blocking yourself from editing the records. `DoCmd.TransferText` by itself should suffice to import the records if this scenario's assumption is true.

For future purposes note you can insert code with greater legibility by clicking the Code Sample icon or pressing Ctrl + K when writing your submission.